# After Forced Reboot, Passwords and SSL Not Working

Tags: macos, password, reboot

I was having problems with my Mac Mini, stuff like the Finder not responding, so I restarted.   I tried it the 'correct' way to begin with, i.e. apple menu, and then restart.  All of the windows seemed to close down correctly, and the Dock and menu bar were the only things visible.  This was taking a while so I went out and did some errands.  I got back two hours later and the same screen was showing.  I started the Terminal and ran `sudo reboot`.   Again, two hours of nothing.

I cycled the power.

The Mac is now working in that I have access to Finder etc.  But every single browser I use (Firefox, Safari, Opera and Chrome) has stopped storing passwords and has hosed all the passwords that were previously stored.  And I can no longer send mail from Mail.app as there is an SSL error.  Server-side, the log says:

```
Apr 29 12:13:12 mail sendmail[15639]: xHdsgddff9dfD: xxxx.invalid.com [192.168.1.31] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA
```

Comment: Is the clock correctly synchronized ? SSL servers rely on the time of the system and it needs to be correct/within a small range

Comment: Ah, that's interesting!  There was about sixty seconds between the Mac and the MX.  Now, is that a fault on the mail server (where ntpd had in fact stopped?), or on the Mac?  I'll need to look into this.  Thanks for that.